# A possible function for the floor function, ceiling function, and rounding function

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So, I was playing around with desmos, and was curious to find a function for finding the floor, ceiling, and a formula to round a number. I came up with this, using summations:

Rounding function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{|h|}} h - \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{-x}{|h|}} h$$

Floor function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x - 0.5}{|h|}} h - \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{0.5 - x}{|h|}} h$$

Ceiling function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x+0.49999...999}{|h|}} h - \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{-(x+0.49999...999)}{|h|}} h$$

Now, let me go over what all the variables here mean. $z$ and $w$ are only placeholder variables for the actual functions because I can't seem to be able to fit more than 1 character on the top of the sigma symbol for the summation. x is the value that has to be rounded off. $k$ is a place holder value for the 3 values -0.5, 0, and 0.5, over which I'll go over soon. $x$ is the number that needs to be estimated. $h$ is the number to who's multiple $x$ is being rounded off to. For example, if $x$ is 11.3, and $h$ is 3, then the estimated value is 3 (we're assuming $k$ is 0 over here). This is the rounding function.

The floor function is similar, except 0.5 is subtracted from $x$, and the same process happens. For the standard function, where it rounds off the number to it's closest lower integer, the value of $h$ would be 1. However, if you would like for it to round it off to the lower integer it is between of any other number's multiple, you can set the value of $h$ as the number who's multiples you wish to use for this to get the job done.

The same should be said for the ceiling function, except it gives the higher integer it is closest to.

I would like to know your opinion on this, and other functions for this purpose that have been created. I would also be interested in knowing if there is any way to make this more efficient.

I would also like to link the [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqsmbd0avu) I used to play around with it, so you can also check it out. Any further help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand... why?  The floor function as it is traditionally used is perfectly easy to understand, perfectly easy to code, perfectly easy to write... what is the point in trying to use a convoluted mess to have the result behave like the floor function just to avoid writing it how it usually is written?

Comment: @JMoravitz I know it is quite simply written as it is. I just wanted to find a function of sorts using existing math functions, just like I did for finding the remainder and quotient of 2 numbers. It's merely a project I'm doing for fun.

Comment: "*What is your opinion on this*" It seems silly, but not technically wrong.  It feels like trying to rewrite $f(x)=x+1$ while avoiding the character for $1$ by doing something like $f(x)=x+23-22$.  Sure... it can be done, but I don't see the point.  "*...possible to fit more than 1 character on the top...*"  `$\sum_{bottomstuff}^{topstuff}n$` produces $\sum_{bottomstuff}^{topstuff}n$, or even better yet as `$\sum\limits_{bottomstuff}^{topstuff}n$` to get $\sum\limits_{bottomstuff}^{topstuff}n$

Comment: @JMoravitz Absolutely agreed, but it is just an on going passion project of mine. The simply connectivity between numbers excites me, and I wanna have fun with it. Also, for the summations thing, could it be possible to do it for the display version of summations?

Comment: *Especially* since the way the summation code is implemented, you are just flooring the top index of the summation to know when to stop.  All you have done is disguise the usage of the floor function in a different way without actually avoiding having used it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I suppose, but I found it interesting, so I posted it here. I was kind of thinking on posting my first ever youtube video on this very thing I found, lol. I perfectly see your point though, and it is absolutely understandable.